# Are the PDC 2009 videos released?

Tags: video

Last year they had http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/ but I dont see http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2009/. Do they plan to release the videos this year?

EDIT:

Within about 24 hours of the breakout session occuring, they will publish the media from the session over on http://microsoftpdc.com

EDIT1:
Not a lot changed yet but they have the link to the videos on the site http://microsoftpdc.com/Videos

EDIT2:

The weekend is saved. videos are online at http://microsoftpdc.com/Videos. I liked the fiddler show.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807862/what-news-talk-from-the-microsoft-pdc-2009-will-have-the-most-effect-on-you-as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://microsoftpdc.com/Videos

More info. and some potentially missed videos here as well:

http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2009/11/pdc09-session-video-list-okay-so-i-lied.html

Answer (score 1):

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/NicFill/Channel-9-Live-at-PDC09-Schedule/

i think you can see it there.....

Comment: That's just Channel 9 Live, which is one particular video stream - the OP is talking about the session videos

Comment: The page has the answer. We have to wait:

We are. Within about 24 hours of the breakout session occuring, we will publish the media from the session over on http://microsoftpdc.com